# find elements in two lists which contain substrings

Tags: python, list-comprehension, string-matching

I have two lists, potentially of different lengths. Each list contains filenames in the form of strings. I don't have control over the names, but I'm assured that the name structure won't change. It will always be something like name1_name2_number1_+(or-)number2.jpg

Number1 is the substring I want to match between the two lists. If the filename in one list contains the same number1 as a filename in the other list, I want to append both those file names to a third list. I have a simple function that will get the number1's in a given list, e.g:

```
>>>list1 = ['serentity01_20malcolm_200_+3.jpg','inara03_kaley40_8000_-1.jpg']
>>>def GetNum(imgStrings):
...    ss = []
...    for b in imgStrings:
...        ss.append([w for w in b.split('_') if w.isdigit()])
...    #flatten zee list of lists because it is ugly.
...    return [val for subl in ss for val in subl]
>>>GetNum(list1)
['200', '800]
```

So, for

```
>>>list1 = ['serentity01_20malcolm_200_+3.jpg','inara03_kaley40_8000_-1.jpg']
>>>list2 = ['inara03_summer40_8000_-2.jpg', 'book23_42jayne_400_+2.jpg', 'summer53_21simon_300_-1.jpg']
>>>awesomesauceSubstringMatcher(list1, list2)
['inara03_kaley40_8000_-1.jpg', 'inara03_summer40_8000_-2.jpg']
```

I feel I should be able to do it with my GetNum function and some list comprehension, but the niftiness that is the whole '[blah for blah in ...]' syntax is new to me, and I can't quite wrap my head around this one. Thoughts? Suggestions? Death threats? Thanks to all helpful responses in advance, and a thousand apologies if my googlefu has failed me in trying to find a similar question/answer.

**EDIT**
I just figured this solution out:

```
[str for str in list1+list2 if any(subs in str for subs in GetNum(list1)) and any(subs in str for subs in GetNum(list2))]
```

I know it's long and ugly, but I really wanted to prove to myself that it could be done with list comprehension. Thanks for all the helpful responses!

Comment: There is a solution given using map-reduce too :)

Answer (score 2):

```
list1 = ['serentity01_20malcolm_200_+3.jpg','inara03_kaley40_8000_-1.jpg']
list2 = ['inara03_summer40_8000_-2.jpg', 'book23_42jayne_400_+2.jpg', 'summer53_21simon_300_-1.jpg']

def getNum(image_name_list):
    for s in image_name_list:
        s = s.split('_')[2]
        if s.isdigit():
           yield s        
        else:
            yield None

def getMatchingIndex(list1, list2):
    other_list = list(getNum(list2))
    for (i, num) in enumerate(getNum(list1)):
        if not num:
            continue
        for (j, other_num) in enumerate(getNum(list2)):
            if (num == other_num):
                yield (i, j)

for i1, i2 in getMatchingIndex(list1, list2):
    print list1[i1], list2[i2]
```

Since we only need to compare one item at a time to every time in the second list, I used a generator in getNum to save memory. Since a number might match more than once, I keep checking through each item.

Comment: Thanks! I also just figured out this solution:

`[m for m in list1+list2 if any(s in m for s in GetNum(list1)) and any(t in m for t in GetNum(list2))]`

Comment: @akimai A lot less code and nicely pythonic, but more CPU and memory usage in the process.

Comment: I love how the term 'pythonic' can be used as both a compliment and an insult for a given piece of code. ^ _^

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but the logic should be correct:

```
list1 = ['serentity01_20malcolm_200_+3.jpg','inara03_kaley40_8000_-1.jpg']
list2 = ['inara03_summer40_8000_-2.jpg', 'book23_42jayne_400_+2.jpg', 'summer53_21simon_300_-1.jpg']
list3 = []

seenInList1Dict = {}

for element in list1:
    splitelem = element.split('_')
    seenInList1Dict[splitelem[2]] = 1

for element in list2:
    splitelem = element.split('_')
    if splitelem[2] in seenInList1Dict:
        list3.append(element)
```

I didn't use your `GetNum` because it unnecessarily complicates things IMO. I find it's easier to just dump things into a dictionary if you want to quickly find/compare the existence of them later. Also if you want the number you just need to do a `split` on the filenames and grab the value you want from the appropriate index.

Comment: Thank you! I made the GetNum because there's a definite chance that there will be multiple numbers we want to get.

Answer (score 0):

I would build a dictionary for both lists where the key is the number from the filename and the value is the filename itself. Then "intersect" the two sets of keys, the resulting common keys could then be used to build up the third list, e.g:

```
def List2Dic(List):
    return dict(map(lambda x: [ x.split("_")[2], x], List))

list1 = ['serentity01_20malcolm_200_+3.jpg','inara03_kaley40_8000_-1.jpg']
list2 = ['inara03_summer40_8000_-2.jpg', 'book23_42jayne_400_+2.jpg', 'summer53_21simon_300_-1.jpg']

d1 = List2Dic(list1)
d2 = List2Dic(list2)

for x in set(d1) & set(d2):
    print d1[x], d2[x]
```

Comment: The op can have multiple filenames repeated in the lists. So, should not use this

Answer (score 0):

Parse the strings into data you can actually sift through. Things will be much easier then.

```
def process(filename):
    splitup = filename.rstrip('.jpg').split('_')
    keys = ["name1", "name2", "number1", "number2"]
    r = dict(zip(keys, splitup))
    r["filename"] = filename
    return r

list1 = ['serentity01_20malcolm_200_+3.jpg','inara03_kaley40_8000_-1.jpg']
list2 = ['inara03_summer40_8000_-2.jpg', 'book23_42jayne_400_+2.jpg', 'summer53_21simon_300_-1.jpg']

plist1 = [process(f) for f in list1]
plist2 = [process(f) for f in list2]

nlist1 = [i['number1'] for i in plist1]
nlist2 = [i['number1'] for i in plist2]

ilist1 = [i for i in plist1 if i['number1'] in nlist2]
ilist2 = [i for i in plist2 if i['number1'] in nlist1]

intersection = set([i["filename"] for i in ilist1 + ilist2])

for i in intersection:
    print i
```

Edit: shoot, I see now you want intersections from both lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
My bit of the solution using map,reduce, filter and list flattening using sum:-
l=['a_b_1_2','b_c_2_3']
s=['c_d_3_4','d_e_1_4']
a=map(lambda y: map(lambda z:  [y,z] if y[2] == z[2] else '', map(lambda v:v.split('_'), s)),map(lambda x:x.split('_'),l))

map(lambda x: '_'.join(x), sum(filter(lambda qq: qq is not '',sum(a,[]))))
```

Showing it on the actual dataset:

```
>>> list1 = ['serentity01_20malcolm_200_+3.jpg','inara03_kaley40_8000_-1.jpg']    
>>> list2 = ['inara03_summer40_8000_-2.jpg', 'book23_42jayne_400_+2.jpg', 'summer53_21simon_300_-1.jpg']

>>> a=map(lambda y: map(lambda z:  [y,z] if y[2] == z[2] else '', map(lambda v:v.split('_'), list2)),map(lambda x:x.split('_'),list1))

>>> a 

    [['', '', ''], [[['inara03', 'kaley40', '8000', '-1.jpg'], ['inara03', 'summer40', '8000', '-2.jpg']], '', '']]


>>> sum(filter(lambda qq: qq is not '',sum(a,[])),[])

    [['inara03', 'kaley40', '8000', '-1.jpg'], ['inara03', 'summer40', '8000', '-2.jpg']]

>>> map(lambda x: '_'.join(x), sum(filter(lambda qq: qq is not '',sum(a,[])),[]))

    ['inara03_kaley40_8000_-1.jpg', 'inara03_summer40_8000_-2.jpg'] #This is the output you want.
```

Comment: Formatted it. Hope it looks clean now.

Answer (score 0):

This returns a list of all the matching values in both lists.  For example if there are matches for the number 8000 and 300, it will return a list full of list for each number possible, and then populate the lists with only the matches.

```
list1 = ['serentity01_20malcolm_200_+3.jpg','inara03_kaley40_8000_-1.jpg',
         'inara03_34simon_300_+1.jpg']
list2 = ['inara03_summer40_8000_-2.jpg', 'book23_42jayne_400_+2.jpg',
         'summer53_21simon_300_-1.jpg']

def GetNum(imgStrings):
    ss = []
    for b in imgStrings:
        ss.append([w for w in b.split('_') if w.isdigit()])
        #flatten zee list of lists because it is ugly.
    return [val for subl in ss for val in subl]


print GetNum(list1)



def addToThird(input1, input2):

    numlist1 = GetNum(input1)
    numlist2 = GetNum(input2)

    numgroups = set(numlist1 + numlist2)
    numgroups = list(numgroups)
    collectionsList = []

    for i in numgroups:
    collectionsList.append([])

    for item1 in numlist1:
        for item2 in numlist2:
            if item1 == item2:
                print item1, item2
                goindex = numgroups.index(item1)
                collectionsList[goindex].append(input1[numlist1.index(item1)])
                collectionsList[goindex].append(input1[numlist2.index(item2)])
    return collectionsList


print addToThird(list1, list2)
```

output:

```
['200', '8000', '300']
8000 8000
300 300
[['inara03_34simon_300_+1.jpg', 'inara03_34simon_300_+1.jpg'], [], 
'inara03_kaley40_8000_-1.jpg', 'serentity01_20malcolm_200_+3.jpg'], []]
```